# How to dock Buttons around a GroupBox in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have a lots of `Button`s in a `Toolstrip`.
Under that strip I have a `GroupBox` (with `Textbox`es & `Label`s inside it).

I want to dock all buttons around my GroupBox (from top to right and down)

[image]

How I can implement this in WinForms??

Best Regards!!

Comment: It's really hard to understand...  Can you edit another image to show us the expected results?

Comment: You could use one or more [FlowLayoutPanels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel?view=netcore-3.1), which would automatically place your controls while arranging and wrapping them for you.  Not sure how to deal with the top ToolStrip, though...you'd have to figure out a way to determine how many buttons fit in the current width and then move the rest into the FlowLayoutPanel in the form of a normal button.  You might be able to convert the top toolstrip into a FlowLayoutPanel.